# How do I get the secret from Azure Key Vault using reactor java?

Tags: java, azure, project-reactor, azure-keyvault

I'm currently working in a microservice using reactor. I've implemented this method to return an asyncrhonous KeyVaultSecret, but when i debug the code I get a value like "MonoLiftFuseable". I've looked why is that value shows but i haven't found much information.

Method in java:

public Mono retrieveParamSecret(String secretName) {

```
ClientSecretCredential paramClientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder()
        .clientId(paramClientId)
        .clientSecret(paramClientKey)
        .tenantId(paramTenantId)
        .build();

SecretAsyncClient paramSecretClient = new SecretClientBuilder()
        .credential(paramClientSecretCredential)
        .vaultUrl(paramVaultUrl)
        .httpLogOptions(new HttpLogOptions().setLogLevel(HttpLogDetailLevel.BODY_AND_HEADERS))
        .buildAsyncClient();

return paramSecretClient.getSecret(secretName);
```

}

MainService:

Mono keyVaultSecretParam = azureKeyVaultService.retrieveParamSecret("KV_PARAMS");

```
    keyVaultSecretParam.map(secretWithVersion ->
            System.out.printf("Secret is returned with name %s and value %s %n",
                    secretWithVersion.getName(), secretWithVersion.getValue()));
```

Sidenote: In the main service implementation class it doesn't enter in the map to print the values.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmECQ.png)

I've tried to keep the SecretClient and use a Mono.fromCallable but I get the same value
I've looked in the Microsoft page about the SecretAsyncClient and it says I need to subscribe it, but when I do that It shows an error for FlapNotNull.

Official page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.security.keyvault.secrets.secretasyncclient?view=azure-java-stable

Update:

When I use the subscribe to print the value obtain, AzureKeyVault gives me this error "code":"Unauthorized","message":"AKV10000: Request is missing a Bearer or PoP token.

And reactor shows : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: reactor.core.publisher.Mono.mapNotNull(Ljava/util/function/Function;)Lreactor/core/publisher/Mono;

Code:

[Code and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iJQj.png)

Comment: Please tidy up the code formatting and include the .subscribe() code that extracts the secret from the Mono and causes a FlapNotNull.

Comment: I added the subscribe and it gives the error "Unauthorized\",\"message\":\"AKV10000: Request is missing a Bearer or PoP token."   and reactor shows  "reactor.core.publisher.Mono.mapNotNull(Ljava/util/function/Function;)Lreactor/core/publisher/Mono"

Comment: Perfect. Now you know why it’s failing. The call to Vault is missing the “Authorization”:”Bearer token” header. Google the error message (maybe even the error code) and Vault and you should make some progress.

Comment: The thing is, I'm creating the ClientSecretCredential with the clientId, clientSecret and the tenantId with the values obtained from the portal, and it still gives me the same error. I have tried with a weblfux application, but using SecreCliente instead of SecretASyncClient, and it brings me the value of the secret, it works fine in that project ..    the credentials are ok and i have full access..

Comment: There must be a different way of adding the Bearer or PoP token with the Async route. Can’t find anything helpful on Google though.☹️

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your requirement in my environment by using the below code and got expected results:

**Note:** I have configured my credentials in my environment.

***Code Snippet:***

```java
@RestController
public class AzureKeyReactorController {

@GetMapping("/data")
public String getSecret() {

SecretClient secretClient = new SecretClientBuilder().vaultUrl("https://mykey7.vault.azure.net/")

.credential(new DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder().build()).buildClient();

KeyVaultSecret secretMono = secretClient.getSecret("mysecret");

String secretValue = secretMono.getValue();

System.out.println(secretValue);
return "My Stored Secret is : " + secretValue;
}
}
```

Firstly, Created KeyVault without giving permission or without adding it to my service principal and I was getting *Access Denied* error as shown below:

[image]

But after giving Access Control to my service principal for this KeyVault which I have created, I'm able to get the secret from the KeyVault.

- *Storing the test secret and I'm able to fetch the same through the code.*

[image]

***Console output:***
[image]

***Result:***

Able to fetch secret value:
[image]

Comment: Yes! I've tried that too and works fine, but not in a reactor 3.0. When using reactive programming it brings me the error block()/blockFirst()/blockLast(). That's why I'm trying to use the SecretAsyncClient because it returns a Mono<KeyVaultSecret>